# About rabbitmq, how to achieve that if in 10s don't receive any message, throw exception or execute some method?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using spring boot and rabbitmq.

How to achieve that if in 10s don't receive any message, throw exception or execute some method?

I try to use multi-thread, but don't finished.

I need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [Detecting Idle Asynchronous Consumers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#idle-containers) in the documentation.

> Starting with version 1.6, it is now possible to configure the listener container to publish a ListenerContainerIdleEvent when some time passes with no message delivery. While the container is idle, an event will be published every idleEventInterval milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read the document. if I use spring-boot with rabbitmq, how do I use the attribute **IdleEventInterval** in annotation  **@RabbitListener**?  Have any examples?